Why does pytorch fabric print test metrics twice, and how to fix it?
I cannot find the answer to this in the docs. When I train on multiple GPUs, and run the test, I get two outputs for performance metrics, one for each GPU. How can I ensure results from all GPUs are combined to report the performance for the whole validation and test set?
$ python script.py --devices 2 --strategy ddp --num_epochs 2
Files already downloaded and verified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

Using 16-bit Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP)
Initializing distributed: GLOBAL_RANK: 0, MEMBER: 1/2
Files already downloaded and verified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

Initializing distributed: GLOBAL_RANK: 1, MEMBER: 2/2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
distributed_backend=nccl
All distributed processes registered. Starting with 2 processes
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Epoch 1/2 - Train Loss: 2.0048, Train Accuracy: 36.60%
Epoch 1/2 - Train Loss: 2.0088, Train Accuracy: 36.33%
Validation - Loss: 1.5226, Accuracy: 44.72%
Validation - Loss: 1.5125, Accuracy: 45.12%
Epoch 2/2 - Train Loss: 1.6508, Train Accuracy: 41.46%
Epoch 2/2 - Train Loss: 1.6423, Train Accuracy: 41.69%
Validation - Loss: 1.4491, Accuracy: 47.56%
Validation - Loss: 1.4460, Accuracy: 48.64%
Files already downloaded and verified
Files already downloaded and verified
Test Loss: 1.4365, Test Accuracy: 47.42%
Test Loss: 1.4634, Test Accuracy: 47.32%

script.py
import os
import torch
import torchvision as tv
import lightning as L
import argparse
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Subset, DistributedSampler
import numpy as np
import torch.distributed as dist

def load_data(data_dir):
    transform = tv.transforms.Compose([
        tv.transforms.ToTensor(),
        tv.transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    ])
    dataset = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(root=data_dir, train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    return dataset

def split_train_val(dataset, val_size):
    """ Randomly split the dataset into training and validation subsets """
    indices = np.arange(len(dataset))
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
    split = int(np.floor(val_size * len(dataset)))
    train_indices, val_indices = indices[split:], indices[:split]
    train_subset = Subset(dataset, train_indices)
    val_subset = Subset(dataset, val_indices)
    return train_subset, val_subset

def evaluate_model(model, dataloader):
    model.eval()
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    running_loss = 0.0
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in dataloader:
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += predicted.eq(labels).sum().item()
    accuracy = correct / total * 100.0
    return running_loss / total, accuracy

def main():
    # Argument parsing
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Train a CIFAR-10 model")
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=128, help='Batch size for training and validation')
    parser.add_argument('--num_workers', type=int, default=4, help='Number of workers for DataLoader')
    parser.add_argument('--num_epochs', type=int, default=1, help='Number of epochs for training')
    parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=0.01, help='Initial learning rate')
    parser.add_argument('--devices', type=int, default=1, help='Number of GPUs for training')
    parser.add_argument('--num_nodes', type=int, default=1, help='Number of compute nodes')
    parser.add_argument('--strategy', type=str, default='auto', help='Data parallel strategy')
    parser.add_argument('--val_size', type=float, default=0.1, help='Fraction of training data to use for validation')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    data_dir = os.getenv("DATASETS_ROOT", "./data")
    dataset = load_data(data_dir)

    # Randomly split dataset into training and validation subsets
    train_dataset, val_dataset = split_train_val(dataset, args.val_size)

    # Initialize Fabric with distributed settings
    fabric = L.Fabric(
        accelerator="gpu",  # Specify the type of accelerator to use
        devices=args.devices,  # Number of devices per node
        num_nodes=args.num_nodes,  # Number of nodes
        strategy=args.strategy,  # Distributed training strategy
        precision="16-mixed"
    )
    fabric.launch()  # Launch the Fabric environment

    # Initialize ResNet18 model and optimizer with Fabric
    model = tv.models.resnet18()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=args.learning_rate)
    # Setup model and optimizer for distributed training
    model, optimizer = fabric.setup(model, optimizer)

    # Setup data loaders with DistributedSampler for proper data distribution
    train_sampler = DistributedSampler(train_dataset)
    val_sampler = DistributedSampler(val_dataset, shuffle=False)
    
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=False, 
                                  sampler=train_sampler, num_workers=args.num_workers)
    val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=False, 
                                sampler=val_sampler, num_workers=args.num_workers)
    
    # Prepare dataloaders for distributed training
    train_dataloader = fabric.setup_dataloaders(train_dataloader)  
    val_dataloader = fabric.setup_dataloaders(val_dataloader)

    for epoch in range(args.num_epochs):
        model.train()
        running_loss = 0.0
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        for batch_idx, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(outputs, labels)
            fabric.backward(loss)  # Use Fabric's backward method for distributed backward pass
            optimizer.step()
            running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += predicted.eq(labels).sum().item()

        train_loss = running_loss / total
        train_accuracy = correct / total * 100.0
        val_loss, val_accuracy = evaluate_model(model, val_dataloader)
        print(f"{epoch+1}/{args.num_epochs}       {train_loss:.4f}           {train_accuracy:.2f}%          {val_loss:.4f}      {val_accuracy:.2f}%")

    # Test dataset
    transform = tv.transforms.Compose([
        tv.transforms.ToTensor(),
        tv.transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    ])
    test_dataset = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(root=data_dir, train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
    test_sampler = DistributedSampler(test_dataset, shuffle=False)
    test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=False, 
                                 sampler=test_sampler)
    # Prepare dataloader for distributed training
    test_dataloader = fabric.setup_dataloaders(test_dataloader)

    test_loss, test_accuracy = evaluate_model(model, test_dataloader)
    print(f"Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}, Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy:.2f}%")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

